# How To Improve SQL Connection

Tags: java, c#, android, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

Hello every body I'm working on application which is sends data from android app to MS-SQL server and main windows software in C#, which is receives data from MS-SQl server.
The problem is the programs takes too time to build a connection especially in android app some times it crash the app.
By the way the Internet speed some times goes week in our country.
I searched for a solution but not found in internet and I cannot figure out any way to solve it.
And I see the Viber, Watsapp, Massenger ... etc it sends data instantly or synchronously  even if Internet speed is week.
So can I get  some help and suggestion.
And there is a connection Helper method :

---

public Connection connections(){

```
    IP="www.examlple.net";
    DB="DB_test";
    DBUserName="admin";
    DBPassword="*****";    
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy= new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    Connection connection=null;
    String connectionURL=null;
    try {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        connectionURL ="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://"+IP+";DatabaseName="+DB+";integratedSecurity=true;user="+DBUserName+";password="+DBPassword;

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);

    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return connection;
}
```

Comment: If you have slow connection speed there is nothing that you can do. But you can implement a retry process https://medium.com/@pramodsachintha/simple-retry-pattern-in-c-91f2c42934d3

Comment: @pix OK I agree with you but even when internet is good it takes a time to build connection>

Comment: Use a **connection pool**. Better yet, don't execute SQL from a mobile device across the web, but have the mobile device communicate with a web service, which in turn executes the SQL statements. That is what all those apps you mentioned are doing.

Comment: @Andreas is right you should/must use a dedicated webservice.

Comment: The communication protocol used to "talk" with databases typically isn't designed to be used with high latency networks. This makes using the database directly problematic: slow and possibly insecure. It's one of of the reasons why people almost always create an "API*: a web service that deals with the database.

Comment: As i understood from your comments that i use web API instead of direct SQL query.Thanks very much guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, with JTDS you can set both a `loginTimeout` and a `socketTimeout` on a connection string. Refer to the remarks on these [here](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html).

But as others have said, you should go through a web API of some sort. Do you really want to expose your SQL server to the internet?

Also, I just noticed you have specified `integrated security=true`, and you have also specified a username and password. You can't do that. One is for windows auth (integrated security) and the other is for SQL auth (user and password). You would have to use a username and password. But don't. Don't do this. go through a web API.

Comment: Thank man as you and others says i might use web-service instead of direct SQL connection.